# How to inherit dependencies from other libraries in maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I created a custom `my-commons` library with maven. The commons pom contains eg the following dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>de.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging> 

    <properties>
        <!-- workaround for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-603-->
        <maven.build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</maven.build.timestamp>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I installed the custom library into my local repository.
In a different project, I reuse the library. It resolves correctly, so it exists in the repo:

```
<project ...>
    <groupId>de.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.domain</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now in this project I'd like to use a class `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody`.

Problem: the class is not in classpath. So maven complains `[ERROR] cannot find symbol`.
But why?? I'd expect the dependency being inherited!

Sidenote: I'm using Intellij IDEA if that matters. The same problem applies to all "inherited" libraries. The spring-web lib is just an example.

Comment: yup it should work? did you pom complain about not finding the your `my-group my-commons 1.0.0` ?

Comment: Not at all. I can even <ctrl>+click on the my-commons and it opens the commons pom.xml correctly.

Comment: did you create a jar with your `commons pom.xml` ? in this jar , `spring-boot-starter-web` will also be included

Comment: can you provide the full pom.xml of `commons` ?

Comment: I ran `mvn install` on my commons, and I can see the lib being installed into .m2 correctly.

Comment: you dont need this step, just provide ur complete pom.xml

Comment: Added full pom from my commons library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147440/discussion-between-amitk-and-membersound).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: removing the `<maven.build.timestamp>...` `<property>` solved the problem. I don't know why it prevented the inheritance to work properly, especially as I didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if .m2 folder contains the jar you want to use or not. You can use `mvn install` command in commons project to generate the jar. Also you need to add commons project in your project pom that you are running.

Comment: I checked it, and the jar is found in the correct folder.

Comment: did you add your commons library in the project pom you are running?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the artifact for your commons project, through its pom.xml.

Like in my below example i created a separate project where i am using the AWS and some other dependency and then final jar, which i am using in other project :-

My AWS-client pom.xml looks like below :-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.kaamkaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-clients</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>aws-clients</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <aws.sdk.version>1.11.104</aws.sdk.version>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <!--AWS dependency-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mercadopago</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mercadopago</id>
            <url>https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-java/raw/master/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Also, run `mvn clean install` on the `commons` pom, in your case.

And then in all other project where i need to include the aws-client , i use the artifact-id of above project, like below :-

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.kaamkaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Let me know if you have any questions:

Comment: @membersound,  looks like `<packaging>jar</packaging>` is missed in your pom.